# Displacement vector for rotational motion

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, vector-fields, displacement

When I try to find out how to compute work for rotational motion. I found an equation from a [book](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Book%3A_University_Physics_I_-_Mechanics_Sound_Oscillations_and_Waves_(OpenStax)/10%3A_Fixed-Axis_Rotation__Introduction/10.09%3A_Work_and_Power_for_Rotational_Motion) online with a figure and equation as follows:

[image]

$ \vec{s}\ =\vec{\theta}\ \times\vec{r}  $

$Thus,$

$d\vec{s}\ =d\left(\vec{\theta}\ \times\vec{r}\ \right)=d\vec{\theta}\ \times\vec{r}\ +d\vec{r}\ \times\vec{\theta}\ =d\vec{\theta}\ \times\vec{r}\ $

$Note\ that\ d\vec{r}\ is\ zero\ because\ \vec{r}\ is\ fixed\ on\ the\ rigid\ body\ from\ the\ origin\ O\ to\ point\ P.
 $

What I don't understand is that it says $ \vec{s}\ =\vec{\theta}\ \times\vec{r}$, it means the direction of  $ \vec{\theta}\ $ is perpendicular to the direction of $ \vec{s}\ $. However, $ d\vec{s}\ $ and $\hat{\theta}$ are in the same direction in the figure.

In addition, from what I learned in my other physics class: $ d\vec{s}\ = r·d\theta·\hat{\theta} $
and it makes sense to me since $ d\vec{s}\ $ is the infinitesimal arc length in $\hat{\theta}$ direction(⊥ to $ \hat{r} $).

Therefore, I am not comfortable with $ \vec{s}\ =\vec{\theta}\ \times\vec{r}  $ which is claiming that $ \vec{\theta}\ $ is perpendicular to $ \vec{s}\ $. I was wondering if someone could please give me some insights on this?

Reference Book: [Physics book](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Book%3A_University_Physics_I_-_Mechanics_Sound_Oscillations_and_Waves_(OpenStax)/10%3A_Fixed-Axis_Rotation__Introduction/10.09%3A_Work_and_Power_for_Rotational_Motion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a case of the book not clarifying what notation is being used. The vector in the figure, $\hat{\theta}$, is the unit vector which points in the direction of increase of the angle $\theta$.

The vector $\vec{\theta}$, however, is a different vector defined to be the vector out of the page corresponding to the rotation via the right hand rule (see Equation 10.2.2 from the same book [here](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Book%3A_University_Physics_I_-_Mechanics_Sound_Oscillations_and_Waves_(OpenStax)/10%3A_Fixed-Axis_Rotation__Introduction/10.02%3A_Rotational_Variables)). In this case, $\vec{\theta}$ will be a vector out of the page from $O$. The cross product now makes sense, with $\vec{s}$ being perpendicular to both $\vec{\theta}$ and $\vec{r}$.

Comment: I see now. So can I say they write vector equation s  = θ × r because of the right hand rule convention for velocity v = w x r? Thanks!